# Not Equal to operator on pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have written the following reverse function for reversing a linked list, given the first and last node addresses of the linked list. The next member data of the last node may or may not be equal to NULL.

I want the while to terminate when first equals to last->next. But it keeps going.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data{};
    node *next{};
    node() = default;
    node(int d, node *n) : data(d), next(n) {}
};

void reverse(node *first, node *last)
{
    node *temp = nullptr;
    node *nextNode = nullptr;
    while (first != last->next)
    {
        nextNode = first->next;
        first->next = temp;
        temp = first;
        first = nextNode;
    }
}

int main()
{
//creation of linked list
    node *n4 = new node(4, nullptr), *n3 = new node(3, n4), *n2 = new node(2, n3), *n1 = new node(1, n2);

    reverse(n1,n4); //call to reverse function
    node *temp = n4; //printing linked list for debugging
    while (temp)
    {
        cout<< temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function can also be written as follows

```
void reverse(node *first, node *last)
{
    node *temp = nullptr, *nextNode;
    while (first != last)
    {
        nextNode = first->next;
        first->next = temp;
        temp = first;
        first = nextNode;
    }
    first->next=temp;
}
```

and the code run perfectly.

Comment: *"statement (first != last->next) evaluates to true even when both first and last->next point to the same memory address"* - Supplied code does not demonstrate this. Also it is a good idea to create one variable per line.

Comment: For problems with lists, I always recommend you draw out your list using pencil and paper (draw labeled squares for nodes and other variables, arrows for links and pointers in general). Then perform all the operations by erasing and redrawing arrows as needed. Once you get it to work implement it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to your code to see what happens to the pointers in the while loop

```
cout << first << ' ' << last->next << ' ' << (first != last->next) << '\n';
while (first != last->next)
{
    nextNode = first->next;
    first->next = temp;
    temp = first;
    first = nextNode;
    cout << first << ' ' << last->next << ' ' << (first != last->next) << '\n';
}
```

The output was

> ```
> 000001D844AF1A80 0000000000000000 1
> 000001D844AF1EE0 0000000000000000 1
> 000001D844AF2610 0000000000000000 1
> 000001D844AF1E90 0000000000000000 1
> 0000000000000000 000001D844AF2610 1
> ```

As you can see the pointer comparison is working perfectly correctly. The actual problem is that, as you can see in the last line, `first` becomes equal to `nullptr` but `last->next` changes **at the same time**.